# Setting a UIButton from a different class selected

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uibutton

I am aware that this is not a really advanced question, but I feel lost. I have a class that defines a custom table cell style, which contains the desired button I wish to edit. Then in a different class I use this cell type and construct a table view. Then I am writing an `IBAction` to the button of the different class. When the button is tapped, it should remain selected. I have tried several things but I can't get a reference of the button properly to provide the desired outcome.

I am still trying to adapt to Objective-C.

**customcellstyle.m**

```
   #import "imageCellCell.h"

    @implementation imageCellCell

    @synthesize view;
    @synthesize starbtn;


    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
    {
        self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
        if (self) {

            view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
            [self addSubview:view];


    // initiate favorites button       
            starbtn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(243,0, 30, 30)];

            [starbtn setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; 

            [starbtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"startbefore.jpg"]
                               forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [starbtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"startafter.jpg"]
                               forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            [starbtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"startafter.jpg"]
                               forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
            [starbtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"startafter.jpg"]


    [view addSubview:starbtn];
                               forState:UIControlStateHighlighted|UIControlStateSelected|UIControlStateDisabled];
```

**tableclass.m**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSString *CellIdentifier;
NSString *CellIdentifierimg;

    UITableViewCell *cell;
    if (cell == nil) {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            cell = [[imageCellCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierimg];
        } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }
    }




    switch ([indexPath row])
    {
        case 0:
        {

            imageCellCell *firstRowCell = (imageCellCell *)cell;  

            // reference of the favorites button to the buttonclick method

            [firstRowCell.starbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(clickFavButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            firstRowCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


            break;

        }




-(IBAction)clickFavButton:(id)sender{


    customcellstyle *class = [[customcellstyle alloc] init];;


[class.starbtn setSelected:YES];
[class.starbtn setHighlighted:YES];

    [starbtn setSelected:YES];
    [starbtn setHighlighted:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a custom button class where you need to set and handle the button image using it's selected value, i have done same kinda thing for checkbox button like

in .h file

```
@interface MXCheckButton : UIButton {
    BOOL    _checked;
}

@property (nonatomic, setter = setChecked:) BOOL checked;

-(void) setChecked:(BOOL) check;

@end
```

and in your .m file

```
@implementation MXCheckButton
@synthesize checked = _checked;

-(id) init
{
    if( self=[super init] )
    {
        self.checked = NO;
        [self addTarget:self action:@selector(OnCheck:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) awakeFromNib
{
    self.checked = NO;
    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(OnCheck:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

-(void) setChecked:(BOOL) check
{
    _checked = check;
    if( _checked )
    {
        UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"];
        [self setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"];
        [self setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}

-(void) OnCheck:(id) sender
{
    self.checked = !_checked;
}

@end
```

here you just change the image file name and your are ready to go!

Comment: I can manage to change the image without a custom button class. My problem is I cant make the image remain the same/stateselected after the button is clicked.

Comment: yeah, for that you can make a BOOL array size of your tableRow and based on index make them YES or NO for set the image according to them.

Comment: I do not think you understood my issue. It is one uibutton on one tablecell, that when clicked I need it to keep the background image of stateselected instead of getting back to state normal

Comment: I think i have give you he solution which i think should work!

Comment: But how can I use this custom button in my other class? Also I ve read that subclassing UIButton is not functional

Comment: You can use a class in many place as you required and UIButton class extension is functional as depend on requirement and used at many place

Comment: I am creating an instance of your buttons class in another class. But then I need to use the reference of the button in the class in a 3rd class, without having to make a new instance. I tried to declare your button as property in a class as with common UIButtons but it does not recognize it

Comment: you mean you are trying to pass a UIButton object to another class? it should work as it's possible

Comment: Yes I am passing it to one class where i design the button. But then I want to use the button designed in another class to add it in a table. And I can't find a way to move it there. If I make a new instance of your class it won't have the design changes made

Comment: let me show how you are passing the custom UIButton object?

Comment: In my class I use this to create your custom button               MXCheckButton *starbtn = [[MXCheckButton alloc] init];;
        starbtn = [[MXCheckButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(243,0, 30, 30)];

Comment: Then I want to pass the button made into a 3rd class, but without making a new instance of the class, or I have to remake one?

Comment: no you can just define a class property and assign this button object to that but make sure your object is strong!

Comment: Define a class property of the middle class not your buttons subclass right? How do I assign the object/button I made to it? I don't get it

Comment: I made it work. But the images won't show up in the table. And the path to image is correct